# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not create a component

Tags: maven, vespa

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not create a component with id 'com.mydomain.example.ExampleSearcher'. Tried to load class directly, since no bundle was found for spec: basic-search-java. If a bundle with the same name is installed, there is a either a version mismatch or the installed bundle's version contains a qualifier string.

Getting above error during the deployment of application in Vespa.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is most likely caused by deploying the wrong application package. If this is the basic-search-java sample application, you have probably done vespa-deploy on the `src/main/application` folder rather than the `target/application.zip` after building the application with maven.

See https://github.com/vespa-engine/sample-apps/tree/master/basic-search-java for exact steps for deploying this application.

Cheers!